# vector product times a vector

Tags: matrices

Give two column vectors $w$ and $\phi$, it is easy to prove that
$w^T\phi\phi = w^T[\phi\phi^T]$. However, by directly applying matrix association rule, we have 
$w^T\phi\phi = w^T[\phi\phi]$. My question is that why the second $\phi$ should be transposed? I know $\phi\phi$ is probably undefined so the natural thing to do is to transpose the second $\phi$. But there should be some intuitions behind.

Comment: The root issue is, if $c$ is a scalar (or a $1 \times 1$ matrix) and $v$ is a column, then scalar multiplication $cv$ is not matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thanks. As @David K said I was missing a transpose that is the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true in general that $w^T\phi\phi = w^T(\phi\phi^T).$
What is true in general is
$$(w^T\phi\phi)^T = w^T(\phi\phi^T).$$

To show this,
\begin{align}
(w^T\phi\phi)^T &= ((w^T\phi)\phi)^T  
 && \text{because $\phi\phi$ is not possible}\\
 &= (w^T\phi)\phi^T   && \text{because $w^T\phi$ is a scalar}\\
 &= w^T(\phi\phi)^T.
\end{align}

It is the outermost "$T$" of $(w^T\phi\phi)^T$
that causes the second $\phi$ of  $w^T(\phi\phi^T)$ to be transposed.